# Checking whether a linked list is empty in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

i'm trying to understand how is the statement in the while condition `while(C)` checking if a single linked list is empty.

```
node* remove(nodo*C, int y){
    FIFO F;                             
    while(C){                           
    if(C->info==y) {                    
        node* p=C;                  
        C=C->next;                  
        delete p;                   
        }
    else {                          
        F=metti_fondo(F,C);         
        C=C->next;                  
         }                              
     }
    if(F.fine)                          
        F.fine->next=0;                 
    return F.primo;
```

The data type used is:

```
struct node{int info; node* next; node(int a=0, node* b=0){info=a; next=b;}};
```

What i'm not understanding is how the simple reference of the node C is enough to check if the list is not empty. Shouldn't it be `while(C->next == 0)` or something like that? I checked and my version is not working, while the code shown before is working well.

What does it checks exactly when i only reference the node C, without any reference to info or next fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very simple.  A linked list is empty if both the head and tail pointers are NULL.

Comment: Well if it has at least one element it's not empty, why would you want to check for more than one when the condition has already been satisfied?

Comment: Fyi, `while (C)` means "while C is not null".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In case of general double linked one. In a single one is enough the head.

Comment: @thecoder: A singly linked list may have a pointer to the tail node for easily adding to the last node.  This is what I am referring to.

Comment: My constructor however has a default value of 0 for any node. What is the explicit code to get the same effect as `while(C)`? Thanks for the answer, i'm just trying to understand what that statement is checking exactly

Comment: An empty linked list has no nodes, whatever the default contents of a node may be. A more explicit version of `while(C)` is `while(C != NULL)`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are talking aboult what is usually referred to as 'current'. Than yeah, that's true.

Comment: @Mastarius `C` is a pointer, passed into the `remove` function by value and modified in that function by `C = C->next`. The constructor has no part to play in this, it's purely a variable. The explicit version of the test would be `while (C != nullptr)`.

Comment: @Mastarius the statement is checking whether the address held in the local pointer variable `C` is non-null. If it is (non-null), the loop continues. if it isn't, the loop breaks.  It is equivalent to `while (C != nullptr)`. The overall loop appears to be enumerating a linked list, pruning out elements that have an info value of `y` and deleting them outright, otherwise moving them to the `F` fifo. (Note: it has better be moving them or your code has a bug, and you say it works correctly, so...).

Comment: @thecoder: You still don't understand.  If I am inserting into the "middle" of the list, then that would be the *current* pointer.  If I want to quickly append to the list, I would append to the tail node.  In order to accomplish this, the common technique is to have a pointer to the last node, often called the tail pointer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah, it is implementation specific still. One is used to something, other to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that if the linked list is truly "empty" then the pointer would be null. The null value is then converted to false within the if check. C->next == 0 (probably should be checking for null here too) would check if the linked list's first node didn't have a child node.

A linked list is built of nodes and each node points to the next node. In a simple implementation the last node simply points to null.

if we write it as Node(val) -> next then something like
N1(0) -> N2(10) -> N3(3) -> null

We could have
N1(0) -> null

and the list would not be empty, but checking C-> next would still be null. An empty list would just be
null

Answer (score 0):

The conditional while statement evaluates to either true or false, depending on the parameter. In this case, I believe the condition will evaluate to false if the pointer C refers to a null address.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It tests whether "C" is assigned a non-zero value.

In C and C++ a statement is false when it evaluates to zero (0), otherwise it evaluates to true.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if (0)
        std::cout << "never\n";
    if (42)
        std::cout << "always\n";
    if (0.2)
        std::cout << "al.ways\n";
}
```

So a pointer evaluates as `false` when it points to memory address 0 - which is done, in order of correctness, by setting it to `nullptr`, `NULL` or `0` but bear in mind that `NULL` is usually `#define 0` or `#define 0ULL`. The problem with using an integer `0` for pointers is that ... it is an integer. Which can lead to ambiguities:

```
void f(int);
void f(char*);

f(0); // which one?
```

The following code prints "world":

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* p = nullptr;
    if (p)
        std::cout << "hello";
    p = "world";
    if (p)
        std::cout << p;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

(http://ideone.com/iy5GcX)

So in common linked list implementations, end-of-list is represented with a null pointer, and so emptiness can be detected by the head of the list being the end - i.e being a nullptr.

```
Node* head;
/*...*/
if (head) {
    // points to something, list is not empty
}
```

And the construct

```
for (Node* node = head; node; node = node->next) {
    ...
}
```

will "short circuit" if the list is empty: node is initially assigned the value of head. If head is null, the first test will fail `( ... ; node ; ...)` and no iterations will be performed.